# RequestsDependencyWarning with git-review on macOS Sierra

Tags: python, macos-sierra, git-review

I've just upgraded (using `homebrew`), my `git-review` today from 1.26 to 1.27. I've got Python 3 installed on my system as well (macOS Sierra).

When I try to submit patch for review using `git review -R`, I get this error;

```
/usr/local/Cellar/git-review/1.27.0/libexec/vendor/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/__init__.py:91: RequestsDependencyWarning: urllib3 (1.24) or chardet (3.0.4) doesn't match a supported version! RequestsDependencyWarning)
```

I've searched online and came up empty, maybe this is a compatibility issue with the latest version of `git-review` on macOS Sierra with Python packages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it with `brew reinstall git-review`, you can have a try.

Comment: A reinstall as of today 15th Nov at 3:30pm UTC+01 fixed it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

The requests library [defines a highest supported version of urllib3](https://github.com/requests/requests/issues/4673) – when a new version of urllib3 comes out, it is tested and once it is confirmed to work, a new version of requests that supports it is released. This doesn't necessarily mean that the previous version won't work, just that it is untested.

Apparently git-review vendors its dependencies, i.e. it uses a pinned version of the requests and urllib3 libraries. For this release, they seem to be using an untested combination of the two. Git-review continues to work just fine for me, so I think the warning is safe to ignore and should disappear in the next release, when they (hopefully) vendor compatible versions.

All that said, Index's suggestion of reinstalling git-review fixed it for me. (That somehow updated the vendored requests from 2.19.1 to 2.20.0) Not sure what's going on there.

Comment: Sometimes I wonder, I just did a reinstall now again and it fixed it. No more errors, wow :). Thanks for your explanation too, makes sense. :)